Logon trigger with both authorization and log insert
I have created a logon trigger in my SQL Server 2019 instance.
The idea is to have both:

Authorization - control who can logon and who cannot. Ex by hostname, IP .... (for simplicity this below is tied to username - some must logon, some must not)
Log record on each case, authorized to enter, and not authorized

Sample trigger is:
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [trigger_name]
ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'sa'
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN
        INSERT INTO LOG_TABLE ...

    COMMIT TRAN

    IF ORIGINAl_LOGIN() = 'TEST2' 
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
END

I test connecting with users TEST1 and TEST2.
Test:

Connect with user TEST1. User does logon, log is written.
Connect with user TEST2. User does not logon (as expected - trigger error), but the log is NOT written into the LOG_TABLE.

Problem: no log written for TEST2

Beginning a transaction inside a trigger is actually creating a child transaction, because the trigger is already running inside it's own transaction. And child transactions are rolled back if the main transaction is rolled back (if fact there isn't really such a thing as a child transaction - it just looks good).

Doesn't look that good for me - :-)
To my knowledge there is no such thing as Oracle's "Pragma Autonomous Transaction" in MS SQL, and this is my problem.

I don't get it, if you don't want the user to login, why not just disable it?

quoted from question:
"control who can logon and who cannot. Ex by hostname, IP .... (for simplicity this below is tied to username"

Ok, just checking so this is not a security measure, because all of those can be easily spoofed on the tds level

HI @siggermannen.
What is "tds level" ?

I mean, the client connecting to your server (and trigger) can write their own hostname ip, program name to sql server and it will be accepted

Can he do this without being an Administrator ?

You can write the log after you rollback the trigger's transaction. EG
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [only_sa_allowed]
ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'sa'
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN

    IF ORIGINAl_LOGIN() <> 'sa' 
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
    INSERT INTO LOG_TABLE(user_name) values (ORIGINAL_LOGIN());
END


Hi @David Browne
One more thing please.
My failing user does receive: " Logon failed for login 'OMEGACAEVDEV2' due to trigger execution".
Is it possible to show something custom to him ?
I tried adding "RAISERROR('access error',16,1);" before the ROLLBACK, but with no result.
thanks and best regards
Altin

Logon failures are intentionally vague.  The sql log should have more details.

Do you mean it is impossible to prompt user with a custom message (in case is logon is disallowed for logical reasons) ?
